# What does it means when the docker daemon failed to add an interface to sandbox?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I am running several docker containers and decided to reorganize them (split the configurations into folders gathering dependent services instead of having one big heap). Everything was going fine until I moved my [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/) configuration.

I did not change anything in the previous configuration, except enforcing a network common to all containers visible "externally" (outside of the private docker network). It works fine with the 20+ other containers.

```
  hass:
    devices:
      - /dev/serial/by-id/usb-1a86_USB_Serial-if00-port0:/dev/serial/by-id/usb-1a86_USB_Serial-if00-port0
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant:2022.7
    network_mode: host
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /etc/docker/domotique/data/hass:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    depends_on:
      - mqtt
    networks:
      - srv

(...)

networks:
  srv:
    external: true
    name: srv
```

When starting this container I get an error:

```
root@srv /e/d/domotique# docker-compose up hass
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container domotique-mqtt-1  Running                                                                             0.0s
Attaching to domotique-hass-1
Error response from daemon: failed to add interface veth6eb29e9 to sandbox: error setting interface "veth6eb29e9" IP to 172.18.0.33/16: cannot program address 172.18.0.33/16 in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route {Ifindex: 7 Dst: 172.18.0.0/16 Src: 172.18.0.1 Gw: <nil> Flags: [] Table: 254}
```

It disappears when I comment out `network_mode: host`. The running container has then the IP `172.18.0.33/16`.  Removing existing Home Assistant containers to force a recreation does not help.

What does this message mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that I used `network_mode: host` and set at the same time the network to use (`srv`).

Removing the `networks` section solved the issue.